# Invertible elements of the matrix of a non-comutative ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

While I was studying ring theory, I came across the following statement

*Let $R$ a ring (non-comutative in general). Then $U(M_{n}(R))=Gl_{n}(R)$ and if $R$ commutative whe can also deduce that $$ A\in GL_{n}(R) \iff detA\in U(R)$$*

To be honest, I can understand the equivalence but I cannot understand why it may not be true for non-comutative rings and how to prove the first equality when $R$ is not commutative. I can only prove that if $A$ is invertible then $detA\neq 0$ and hence $A\in Gl_{n}(R)$, thus $U(M_{n}(R))\subset Gl_{n}(R)$. But for the other inclusion we know that $detA\neq 0$ and I need somehow to conclude that $detA$ invertible so that I can tell that $A$ invertible.

Comment: Determinants do not make sense for matrices over non-commutative rings.

Comment: So $Gl_{n}(R)$ does not make sense either? Could you please give me more details about your comment? I cannot see from the construction of the determinant why we cannot use a non-comutative ring. @Geoffrey Trang

Comment: It’s not strictly true that “determinants don’t make sense for noncommutative rings” because there has been work done to develop determinants for some of them. It’s just that such theory isn’t standard and the usual definition for commutative rings doesn’t suffice.  You can read about the determinant developed by Dieudinne in Artin’s *Geometric algebra* for example or the wiki page for dieudonne determinant.  Certainly you can’t count on a definition of determinant for all rings at the moment.

Comment: So the equation $U(M_{n}(R))=Gl_{n}(R)$ is true for commutative rings and we are not sure for non-comutative since we can't define the determinant for all rings. But even when we have commutativity, I cannot prove the other inclusion. Let $A\in Gl_{n}(R)$ then $detA\neq 0$ but how can I prove that it is an invertible element of $R$ so that I can prove that $A\in U(M_{n}(R))$???